# Why can't I get response headers from youtube by HTTP 1.1?

Tags: python

In python 3.3, I want to get response headers from a youtube webpage. Using HTTP 1.0, the code below works fine:

```
import socket
PATH='/watch?v=GVIjOr98B7Q'
HOST='www.youtube.com'
buffer = bytes('HEAD %s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n' %(PATH, HOST),'ascii')
PORT=80
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall(buffer)
td=b''
while 1:
 data = s.recv(1024)
 td+=data
 if not data:
  break
```

However, if I replace HTTP 1.0 with HTTP 1.1:

```
buffer = bytes('HEAD %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n' %(PATH, HOST),'ascii')
```

and any other lines remain the same. It will stop at the while loop for a really long time (It is not looping but waiting for the end signal). Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **HTTP 1.1** keeps connections open unless you pass along the header `Connection: close`. See: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

If you want the connection to close immediately either use `HTTP 1.0` or send the header `Connection: close`

Comment: What is the advantage of using HTTP 1.1 on this issue? Is there any difference between these two methods?

Comment: Naively and very simply (*Again read the spcs*): HTTP 1.0 (no persistent connections), HTTP 1.1 (persistent connections)